Upip micropython esp32 no se instala
en todos los lugares que consulte TODOS solo me dicen que es upip y como usarlo pero NADIE NADIE me dice como instalarlo intente instalar con thonny y no funciono, probé importarlo y no funciona, ya comprobé que no esta instalado, repito uso ESP32 CON MICROPYTHON

Tengo instalado MicroPython en ESP8266 y ESP32. Segui las instrucciones en el sitio oficial: https://docs.micropython.org/en/latest/esp32/tutorial/intro.html#esp32-intro. Thonny asume que ya lo tienes instalado.

¿Qué version de MicroPython usas? Si mal no recuerdo MicroPython reemplazó upip por mip hace algún tiempo

Upip fue reemplazado for mip desde hace 2-3 años.
